# No manifests in <dir>/releases/*/assets_manifest.* Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I just noticed I'm getting this error on `cap deploy`:

```
No manifests in <dir>/releases/*/assets_manifest.*
```

This is part of the `cleanup` task and I only started getting it after I added a task to conditionally precompile assets:

```
#precompile assets only when needed
  namespace :assets do
    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      from = source.next_revision(current_revision)
      if capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} vendor/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0
        run %Q{cd #{latest_release} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} #{asset_env} assets:precompile}
      else
        logger.info "Skipping asset pre-compilation because there were no asset changes"
      end
    end
  end
```

Is this an error I need to be concerned with?

Rails 3.2.13

Capistrano 2.15.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deploying with capistrano each release has an `assets_manifest` file which lists all required assets for that release.

When you run cleanup, capistrano aggregates all files which appear in **any** of the `assets_manifest` file of **any** release and deletes all the assets which do not appear in them and they are older than `expire_assets_after`.

Apparently one of your deployments did not have asset changes thus `assets:precompile` did not run and this release directory now misses the assets_manifest file which capistrano looks for in its cleanup task.

If it stops your deploy then you should obviously be concerned about it. Otherwise I'd make a few tests to see that assets are indeed being cleaned up correctly and fix this error in a later time.

By the way - to fix your issue you will probably have to alter the `clean_expired` task of capistrano.
You can find the [exact code here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/8e2238d075ffec6a69afdd404e5ed52003e6775e/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/assets.rb#L126).

Comment: @Tyler-DeWitt, did either of you end up writing a fix for this? I'm experiencing the same issue. Turns out my asset dir is slowly getting filled up